# Having trouble with GameObject lists in C# for unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm in the process of working on what should be a relatively simple scripting exercise, but I am new to Unity scripting and have been stuck on this for way too long.

Basically, the parameters for what I'm working on is as follows:

1. Instantiate one cube prefab every frame into the scene.
2. The cubes need to be named as “Cube1”, “Cube2”… based on the order they are generated.
3. The cubes need to be generated at a random locations within 1 unit from the origin [0,0,0].
4. Each cube should have a random color.
5. The cube size (localScale) shrink 10% in each frame.
6. When the cube’s scale is less than 10% of its original scale, the cube is destroyed.

I am stuck on part two. I can create infinitely as many cube objects as I wish, but me attempting to name them in the list only has them come out as "Cube" every time a new one is created.

Also, I am not sure how to target each cube in the list so that they all shrink and then disappear. So currently as it stands, this just generates cubes of random size and color within 1 unit from the origin, but none of those cubes do anything once they are created.

My code so far:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 origin;
    private List<GameObject> cubeList;
    public float targetScale = 0.1f;
    public float shrinkSpeed = 0.1f;
// Start is called before the first frame update




private void Awake()
{
    cubeList = new List<GameObject>();
}

void Start()
{
    origin = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    AddNewCube();
   
    // RemoveCube(cubeList[i]);
    //i++;


}

private void SetRandCubeState(GameObject cube)
{

    float randScale = Random.Range(0.8f, 1.0f);
    Vector3 randomScaler = new Vector3(randScale, randScale, randScale);
    cube.transform.localScale = randomScaler;
    Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(origin.x - 1.0f, origin.x + 1.0f), Random.Range(origin.y - 1.0f, origin.y + 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f,1.0f));
    cube.transform.localPosition = randomPosition;
    Renderer render = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    render.material.SetColor("_Color", Random.ColorHSV());

}

private void AddNewCube()
{
    GameObject newCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cubeList.Add(newCube);
    SetRandCubeState(newCube);
    for (int i = 0; i == cubeList.Count; i++)
    {
        cubeList[i].name = "cube" + i;
        cubeList[i].transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(cubeList[i].transform.localScale, new Vector3(targetScale, targetScale, targetScale), Time.deltaTime * shrinkSpeed);
        print("i is equal to " + i);
    }


}

private void RemoveCube(GameObject oldCube)
{
    Destroy(oldCube);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is the error you put == so that will not be execute never.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cubeList.Count; i++)
    {
        cubeList[i].name = "cube" + i;
        cubeList[i].transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(cubeList[i].transform.localScale, new Vector3(targetScale, targetScale, targetScale), Time.deltaTime * shrinkSpeed);
        print("i is equal to " + i);
    }
```

Comment: And when you destroy a cube be sure of remove from the list first. if not will throw and exception when you run the for loop after destroy the cube